# Error loading gem 'breadcrumbs_on_rails'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Updated version of ruby in gemset ruby-2.0.0-p247 to ruby-2.2.4.

now when i start the server so error

```
There was an error while trying to load the gem 'breadcrumbs_on_rails'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
Gem Load Error is: private method `alias_method' called for ActionController::Base:Class
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try installing bundler and rails again so they can use the new version of ruby
`gem install bundler`
`gem install rails`

Comment: What is your Rails version of the app?. Check https://github.com/weppos/breadcrumbs_on_rails#requirements its supported for rails 4 and 5